# ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate with sklearn cross_val_predict method

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm trying to model a binary classification problem with custom cross validation folds with SVM classifier but it gives me the error **need at least one array to concatenate ** with the cross_val_predict. The Code works fine with cv=3 in cros_val_predict but when I use custom_cv, it gives this error.

Below is the code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeavePOut
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from time import *
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict,cross_val_score
clf = SVC(kernel='linear',C=25)
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8],[9,10]])
y = np.array([0,1,1,0,0])
lpo = LeavePOut(2)
print(lpo.get_n_splits(X))
LeavePOut(p=2)
test_index_list=[]
train_index_list=[]
for train_index, test_index in lpo.split(X,y):
  
  if(y[test_index[0]]==y[test_index[1]]):
    pass
  else:
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    train_index_list.append(train_index)
    test_index_list.append(test_index)
custom_cv = zip(train_index_list, test_index_list)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=custom_cv)

print(scores)
print('accuracy:',scores.mean())
predicted=cross_val_predict(clf,X,y,cv=custom_cv) # error with this line
print('Confusion matrix:',confusion_matrix(labels, predicted))
```

Below is full trace of error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d78feac932b2> in <module>()
     31 print(scores)
     32 print('accuracy:',scores.mean())
---> 33 predicted=cross_val_predict(clf,X,y,cv=custom_cv)
     34 
     35 print('Confusion matrix:',confusion_matrix(labels, predicted))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_val_predict(estimator, X, y, groups, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, method)
    758     predictions = [pred_block_i for pred_block_i, _ in prediction_blocks]
    759     test_indices = np.concatenate([indices_i
--> 760                                    for _, indices_i in prediction_blocks])
    761 
    762     if not _check_is_permutation(test_indices, _num_samples(X)):

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate
```

Any suggestion about how to solve this error?

Comment: The list arrays given to `np.concatenate` is empty.  I'd have to look more at the `sklearn` code to see how `prediction_blocks` relates to the inputs to `cross_val_predict`.  But you should check the shape of the inputs to that function, in particular `X` and `y`. In other words, check your inputs compared to the function documentation.

Comment: Its mainly problem with custom cross validation  folds which works fine with cross_val_score. If I change cv=cumtom_cv to simple cross validation split say 3 this will run successfully. But I really need to work with this set of train and test indices.

Comment: Wait a minute!  You got this to work with one value, and it fails with another?  Why didn't you give those details initially.  If you really want help don't skimp on the relevant information.  Without experience in this code I was inclined to focus on `x, y`, etc, but seems the `cv` parameter is the real issue.  I don't if give it a `zip()` is ok, or whether it should be `list(zip(...)))` or something else.

Comment: Yes you are right. Will edit the question. I just want to use sample with indices in train_index_list for training and ignoring samples with indics in test_index_list which will be used while predicting.  So it's not necessary to use zip().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 errors here:

1. If you want to reuse `zip` object, create a list out of it. The object gets exhausted after you use it once. You can fix it like this:

```
custom_cv = [*zip(train_index_list, test_index_list)]
```

2. cross validation list for `cross_val_predict` should be partitions of actual array([Each sample should only belong to exactly one test set](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html)). In your case it isn't. If you think about it, stacking output from your cross validation list would result in length **6** array, while original **y** has length 5. You can implement custom cross val predict like this:

```
def custom_cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv):
    y_pred, y_true = [], []
    for tr_idx, vl_idx in cv:
        X_tr, y_tr = X[tr_idx], y[tr_idx]
        X_vl, y_vl = X[vl_idx], y[vl_idx]
        clf.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
        y_true.extend(y_vl)
        y_pred.extend(clf.predict(X_vl))
        
    return y_true, y_pred

labels, predicted = custom_cross_val_predict(clf,X,y,cv=custom_cv)
print('Confusion matrix:',confusion_matrix(labels, predicted))
```

Comment: you are right  by using this logic, cross validation list is repeating samples of X. In this way confusion matrix represent results for more than samples. Any possible way to perform leave pair out cross validation? for every split of cross validation, a pair is taken from both label groups (0,1)?

Comment: @Aizayousaf I suggest you create another question for this new problem, since your question here was already answered.